# Echo &variable% in a loop is delayed by 1 count. Echo is off error

Tags: loops, cmd, echo

Im trying to make a CMD batch script that will do the following.

1. Read the first line of a text file. The first line of the text file contains a date.
2. Delete the text file if the date is 3 months old from current date.

For illustration, 
 the first line of file A is Hello1, the first line of file B is Hello2

I want to get an output showing this
%counter% %first line of text file%,

so for my example it should look like this:

2 Hello2
1 Hello1

but instead, i am getting this:

2
1 Hello2

My current code is this.

```
set file.1=A.txt
set file.2=B.txt
set counter=2

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=%counter%

:loop
if %counter% NEQ 0 (
set /p texte=<!file.%counter%!
echo %counter% %texte%

set /a counter=%counter%-1
gotop loop)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming `gotop` is a typo, yes?

Comment: yes. I will be trying out your solution now. I will get back to you ASAP. Thank you for replying!!

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, your solution is working fine! However, when i run the batch, the CMD window closes almost instantly. I usually make it stay open by adding 

   cmd /k 

at the end but its not working

Comment: I'd suggest running it from a command window rather than double-clicking on it within the file manger. That way, it will stay open *without* a kludge like putting `pause` after the `endlocal` (which is possibly the best way to do it if you *really* don't want to use a command window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set it up for delayed expansion with your `setlocal` command (which should probably have a corresponding `endlocal` by the way) but you don't appear to be *using* delayed expansion in all the places it's needed.

Delayed expansion of variables requires the use of `!` for expansion, *not* `%`.

Of course, once you do that, you're going to find issues with an expression like `!file.!counter!!` because `cmd.exe` is not the, err, *greatest* tool in the world :-)

However, that fact has produced some of the sneakiest *coders* in the world by forcing them to work around such limitations and you can do double-indirection of variables by using `call` as per the following program:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set file.1=A.txt
set file.2=B.txt
set counter=2

:loop
if !counter! NEQ 0 (
    call :sneaky_set fspec file.!counter!
    set /p texte=<!fspec!
    echo !counter! !texte!
    set /a counter=!counter!-1
    goto loop
)

endlocal
goto :eof

:sneaky_set
    set %1=!%2!
    goto :eof
```

The `call` statement there passes`fspec` and `file.N` (the first level of indirection and where `N` is the current value in `counter`) to `sneaky_set`. It in turn executes:

```
set fspec=!file.N!
```

which is the *second* level of indirection and therefore sets `file` to the correct `*.txt` value.